# Finding already-loaded configuration files in Ubuntu (e.g. .Xdefaults)?

Tags: ubuntu, xterm

I accidentally rm'd my `.Xdefaults` and naturally would like it back. Normally of course I'd be SOL but I figure it's still somewhere because when I open a terminal it opens with the configuration from that deleted file. So at the moment I'm trying to find where that loaded `.Xdefaults` is so I can hopefully copy it back into a new file.

Is this even possible? I feel it should be.

Answer (score 1):

**`xrdb -query`** will show all resources currently present in the X11 server.